# Python3 SQLAlchemy sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper or this Session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Working with SQL Alchemy for the first time and I keep getting an error when trying to commit.

Python3
SQLAlchemy 1.0.12

#### database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.test")
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import src.models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

#### models.py

```
from datetime import datetime

from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import Column, Table
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from src.database import Base

class Answer(Base):
    """
    The answer for a question.
    """
    __tablename__ = "answer"

    answer_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    answer = Column(String(), nullable=False, index=True)
    question_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey("question.question_id"))

    question = relationship("Question", back_populates="answer")

    def __init__(self, answer: str, question_id: int = None):
        self.answer = answer
        self.question_id = question_id

class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = "question"

    question_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    question = Column(String(), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    answer = relationship("Answer", uselist=False, back_populates="question")

    def __init__(self, question: str, answer: Answer, options: List[Option] = None):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        if options:
            self.options = options
```

#### Create database

```
>>> from src.database import init_db
>>> init_db()
```

This creates the database as expected

#### Add items to the database

```
>>> from src.models import Question, Answer
>>> a = Answer("Yes")
>>> q = Question("Doctor Who?", a)
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
>>> s = Session()
>>> s.add(a)
>>> s.add(q)
```

Until now I did not get an error

```
>>> s.commit()
```

Here I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|Question|question or this Session
```

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ["Using the Session"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session):

> `sessionmaker` class is normally used to create a top level `Session` configuration

You shouldn't try and create a session using the [`Session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) class directly. Use the `scoped_session` wrapped `sessionmaker` defined in your *database.py*, as it has the correct binding configured etc.:

```
>>> from src.models import Question, Answer
>>> from src.database import db_session
>>> a = Answer("Yes")
>>> q = Question("Doctor Who?", a)
>>> s = db_session()
>>> s.add(a)
>>> s.add(q)
>>> s.commit()
```

You could also use a [`scoped_session` as a proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#implicit-method-access).